# How to check duplicated function name in jQuery.fn.extend on webpack building

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

extendFunctions1.js

```
function func1Duplicated() { }
function func2() { }
function func3() { }
// ...
// ...
```

extendFunctions2.js

```
function func4() { }
function func5() { }
function func1Duplicated() { }
// ...
// ...
```

I want to add a task, that extends custom functions to jquery.fn.extend(), on webpack build.

How can I check the duplicated function name on making the bundle.js file. 
like the 'function1Duplicated'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in javascript to find duplicated functions name

your **func1Duplicated** method is going to redefined and the last one gonna be call whenever you call **func1Duplicated**

you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911725/functions-with-same-names-in-javascript) for more information